# Jquery animate attribute change

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Is there a way to do animation of attribute change in jquery the same way you can do it with .switchClass() function?

class should stay the same by the attribute value changes for the element.

here is jsfiddle that shows what i want to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/9nh348sb/

Code:
html

```
<div class="big" id="1"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
  .big[id="1"] {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  .big[id="2"] {
    background-color: #00f;
  }
```

JS:

```
$( "div" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).switchClass( 'big[id=1]', 'big[id=2]', 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this

```
setInterval(function(){
$('div').toggle(function(){
                     $(this).attr('id','1');
                     return false;
                 },function(){
                     $(this).attr('id','2');
                     return false;
                 });
},1000);
```

Comment: i doesnt work for me, the div just disappears here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9nh348sb/2/

Comment: @AnKing I saw fiddle, If you want to perform simple animation irrespective click events you needs swap id setter in handlers based html's current value. here is updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9nh348sb/4/

Comment: You can't perform toggle of click of div, since once div gets hidden you can't perform click. but if want to perform on click of document here is updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9nh348sb/5/